How to resolve telnet connection timeout in GCP IPSec VPN setup
We are trying to connect to an external service using IPSec, and the VPN is well established. However, when we try to run telnet, we always get the following error:
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

We are using GCP's gcloud commands to configure the network, VPN, and firewall. The relevant commands used for setting up the VPN and firewall are as follows:
Gcloud commands
gcloud compute networks create sandbox-network \
  --subnet-mode custom

gcloud compute networks subnets create sandbox-network-subnet \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --region us-central1 \
  --range 10.0.0.0/24 \
  --enable-flow-logs

gcloud compute addresses create sandbox-ip \
  --region us-central1

gcloud compute addresses create sandbox-nat-ip \
  --region us-central1

gcloud compute target-vpn-gateways create sandbox-vpn-gateway \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --region us-central1

gcloud compute firewall-rules create sandbox-allow-vpn-traffic \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --allow tcp,udp,icmp,esp \
  --direction INGRESS \
  --enable-logging

gcloud compute forwarding-rules create sandbox-rule-esp \
  --region us-central1 \
  --ip-protocol ESP \
  --target-vpn-gateway sandbox-vpn-gateway \
  --address $(gcloud compute addresses describe sandbox-ip --region us-central1 --format "get(address)")

gcloud compute forwarding-rules create sandbox-rule-udp500 \
  --region us-central1 \
  --ip-protocol UDP \
  --ports 500 \
  --target-vpn-gateway sandbox-vpn-gateway \
  --address $(gcloud compute addresses describe sandbox-ip --region us-central1 --format "get(address)")

gcloud compute forwarding-rules create sandbox-rule-udp4500 \
  --region us-central1 \
  --ip-protocol UDP \
  --ports 4500 \
  --target-vpn-gateway sandbox-vpn-gateway \
  --address $(gcloud compute addresses describe sandbox-ip --region us-central1 --format "get(address)")

gcloud compute firewall-rules create sandbox-allow-ingress \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --allow all \
  --direction INGRESS \
  --priority 1000 \
  --enable-logging

gcloud compute firewall-rules create sandbox-allow-egress \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --allow all \
  --direction EGRESS \
  --priority 1000 \
  --enable-logging

gcloud compute vpn-tunnels create sandbox-vpn-tunnel \
  --region us-central1 \
  --peer-address SERVICE_PEER_IP \
  --ike-version 2 \
  --shared-secret YOUR_SHARED_SECRET \
  --target-vpn-gateway sandbox-vpn-gateway \
  --local-traffic-selector 0.0.0.0/0 \
  --remote-traffic-selector SERVICE_SNAT_IP

gcloud compute routes create sandbox-vpn-route \
  --network sandbox-network \
  --next-hop-vpn-tunnel sandbox-vpn-tunnel \
  --next-hop-vpn-tunnel-region us-central1 \
  --destination-range SERVICE_SNAT_IP

gcloud compute routers create sandbox-router \
  --region us-central1 \
  --network sandbox-network

gcloud compute routers nats create sandbox-router-nat-config \
  --router sandbox-router \
  --region us-central1 \
  --nat-all-subnet-ip-ranges \
  --enable-endpoint-independent-mapping \
  --nat-external-ip-pool sandbox-nat-ip \
  --log-filter ALL \
  --enable-logging

Observations:

We can see that the firewall rules allow traffic, but telnet still times out.
The egress firewall seems to allow the traffic according to the logs:

{
  "insertId": "INSERT_ID",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "instance": {
      "zone": "us-central1-a",
      "project_id": "OUR_PROJECT",
      "vm_name": "sandbox-test-vm",
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "vpc": {
      "project_id": "OUR_PROJECT",
      "vpc_name": "sandbox-network",
      "subnetwork_name": "sandbox-network-subnet"
    },
    "remote_instance": {
      "project_id": "OUR_PROJECT"
    },
    "connection": {
      "src_ip": "10.0.0.7",
      "protocol": 17,
      "dest_ip": "SERVICE_SNAT_IP",
      "src_port": 60248,
      "dest_port": 33523
    },
    "remote_vpc": {
      "vpc_name": "sandbox-network",
      "project_id": "OUR_PROJECT"
    },
    "rule_details": {
      "action": "ALLOW",
      "direction": "EGRESS",
      "priority": 1000,
      "ip_port_info": [
        {
          "ip_protocol": "ALL"
        }
      ],
      "destination_range": [
        "SERVICE_SNAT_IP/32"
      ],
      "reference": "network:sandbox-network/firewall:sandbox-allow-egress"
    },
    "disposition": "ALLOWED"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "gce_subnetwork",
    "labels": {
      "subnetwork_name": "sandbox-network-subnet",
      "project_id": "OUR_PROJECT",
      "subnetwork_id": "4135552741745782047",
      "location": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-10-20T16:16:20.745323759Z",
  "logName": "projects/OUR_PROJECT/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Ffirewall",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-10-20T16:16:29.827308188Z"
}

VM Instance
gcloud compute instances create sandbox-test-vm \
  --zone=us-central1-a \
  --machine-type=e2-medium \
  --network=sandbox-network \
  --subnet=sandbox-network-subnet \
  --image-family=debian-12 \
  --image-project=debian-cloud \
  --can-ip-forward \
  --no-restart-on-failure \
  --no-address \
  --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
  --tags=sandbox-test-vm \
  --boot-disk-size=10GB

gcloud compute firewall-rules create sandbox-allow-icmp-ssh \
  --network=sandbox-network \
  --allow=tcp:22,icmp \
  --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 \
  --target-tags=sandbox-test-vm

Debug Steps Taken:

We attempted to debug the connection using telnet:

sudo telnet SERVICE_SNAT_IP 443 --debug
Trying SERVICE_SNAT_IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out


traceroute also shows no response:

traceroute SERVICE_SNAT_IP
traceroute to SERVICE_SNAT_IP (SERVICE_SNAT_IP), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

What might be causing the telnet connection to time out despite the firewall allowing the traffic? Are there any additional firewall rules or network settings required when setting up IPSec VPN with GCP to allow traffic through?
Any guidance on modifying the firewall rules or network configuration to resolve this issue would be appreciated!
